# Angular - force redirect to a certain page

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

In my app there's a certain wizard with several steps the user must finish before using the app. Each step certain data is begin added to an `array`. How can I use this in order to determine how many steps the user finished before getting to the final page? Can I force redirect him to the step he skipped from? E.g typed the url to the final page.

This is my `route` config code:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "homePage.html",
            controller: "homeController"
        }) 
         .when("/summary", {
            templateUrl: "summary.html",
            controller: "summaryController"
        })
        .when("/step/:index", {
            templateUrl: "/step/stepPage.html",
            controller: "stepController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        })
});
```

In the summary page I tried something like this to determine how did the user get to this page. If length of array is 5 then he went through all steps, if less, redirect him back to where he left.

```
if(dataArray.length<5){
    $location.path( "/step/"+dataArray.length );
}
```

This approach always gets me back to the root URL "/". Why?

Comment: Probably because if you are deep linking directly to that view `dataArray` is undefined. What do you get if you `console.log(dataArray.length)`?

Comment: I get the array using a service, I have access to it everywhere.

Comment: Use a service to keep track

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Try to navigate using ui-router states instead, e.g. $state.go(...) and not changing the location directly.

Comment: There are some tips with the `$canActive` hooks that can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router)